# Scrolling and Non-Scrolling versions of a single page app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am writing a single-page app in React. All pages in this app have a header and some content. The header is fixed and the content is scrollable. To do this, I am setting the height to `100%` starting from the `<html>` tag down to the `<Page>` component. The `<Page>` component itself is a flexbox with a fixed-height header and the content area is set up with `flex: 1` and `overflow: auto` to allow for scrolling. Here's a simplified structure of the app using only HTML and CSS:

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .scrolling-page {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 34px;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    .content {
        flex: 1;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 8px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-page">
<header class="header">
    Header
</header>
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur
    mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia
    repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus
    temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas
    assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque
    dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa
    cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima
    obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis
    alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui
    nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur
    vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
    alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui
    nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur
    vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to now create a version of the same page that does not scroll and occupies only the height needed by the page, not 100% of the page. This requires the removal of `100%` heights starting from the `<html>` tag down. However since this is a single-page app, I can't have it both ways. There is only one instance of `<html>`, `<body>` etc. Do you see any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following what you intend to do.. If it's just displaying the "fluid" height version when content is not enough to overflow the viewport and a fixed 100% of the viewport version with scroll bars when content is larger, then max-height 100vh and overflow auto would do the trick

Comment: To clarify, I want two versions of the page, one scrolling and one non-scrolling. However, because it's a single page app, the only thing that I can change between the two versions is the page wrapper. So `<div class="scrolling-page">` can be changed to `<div class="non-scrolling-page">` and the css for `.non-scrolling-page` can change. Everything else needs to be the same. The overall CSS approach can change from what I have, but it still needs to be the same between the scrolling and non-scrolling versions except for the page wrapper. Hope this clarifies.